# I used extract_msg package to extract date from .msg file but I got AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute '_prop. How can I solve this?

Tags: python, email

```
    import extract_msg
    f = r'.msg file    
    msg = extract_msg.Message(f)
```

I get this error when I run the code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\extract_msg\msg.py in mainProperties(self)
    409         try:
--> 410             return self._prop
    411         except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute '_prop'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-115-2c4a84bf5176> in <module>
      2 
      3 f = r'.msg file'  # Replace with yours
----> 4 msg = extract_msg.Message(f)
      5 # msg_sender = msg.sender
      6 # msg_date = msg.date

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\extract_msg\message.py in __init__(self, path, prefix, attachmentClass, filename, delayAttachments, overrideEncoding)
     26 
     27     def __init__(self, path, prefix = '', attachmentClass = Attachment, filename = None, delayAttachments = False, overrideEncoding = None):
---> 28         MessageBase.__init__(self, path, prefix, attachmentClass, filename, delayAttachments, overrideEncoding)
     29 
     30     def dump(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\extract_msg\message_base.py in __init__(self, path, prefix, attachmentClass, filename, delayAttachments, overrideEncoding)
     48         # TODO have each function check for initialization of needed data so these
     49         # lines will be unnecessary.
---> 50         self.mainProperties
     51         self.header
     52         self.recipients

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\extract_msg\msg.py in mainProperties(self)
    410             return self._prop
    411         except AttributeError:
--> 412             self._prop = Properties(self._getStream('__properties_version1.0'),
    413                                     constants.TYPE_MESSAGE if self.prefix == '' else constants.TYPE_MESSAGE_EMBED)
    414             return self._prop

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\extract_msg\properties.py in __init__(self, stream, type, skip)
     50                 if skip == 0:
     51                     skip = 32
---> 52         streams = divide(self.__stream[skip:], 16)
     53         for st in streams:
     54             a = create_prop(st)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\extract_msg\utils.py in divide(string, length)
    141     ['Hello', ' Worl', 'd!']
    142     """
--> 143     return [string[length * x:length * (x + 1)] for x in range(int(cielDiv(len(string), length)))]
    144 
    145 def fromTimeStamp(stamp):

NameError: name 'cielDiv' is not defined
```

I think the code is fine because I tried the same code on another laptop and it worked. The version of the python on my laptop is 3.8.5 and the other one is 3.8.0. I tried the code on both laptops with the same file to be sure that it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Are you using the base/root Conda environment for this? Can you share the version of the major packages used?

Answer (score 0):

I upgrade the package from 0.27.7 to 0.27.8, and the problem is solved.